# Same URL for SVN and ViewVC

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, svn, viewvc

I have SVN and the ViewVC tool on an Apache2 server and was wondering if there was a way to make it so that if you access a URL from the web browser it takes you to ViewVC, but if you access the same URL with say, TortoiseSVN then it does checkouts, etc. properly.

For example, if I open https://website.com/svn/repo1, it takes me to the ViewVC tool, but if I access the same URL with TortoiseSVN then I would be able to do commits, checkouts, etc. with no issue.

Or is it not possible because it can't differentiate between the type of requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the general sense, because Subversion uses GET requests as part of its HTTP(s) network protocol, it would be rather challenging for Apache to distinguish between requests aimed at Subversion and those intended for the ViewVC program.  Now, as it turns out, Subversion clients generally issue GET requests only for the URLs of repository *files*, not directories.  So, in theory if you could configure Apache to handle a GET (and a GET only) of https://website.com/svn/repo1/ (a directory) specially, perhaps redirecting it to another URL where ViewVC *really* lives, then at least the top-level directory could be used in both ways.  But I haven't a prescription myself or any knowledge of prior art to prove that theory.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was able to do this similar to the way you described in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by putting the following in the Apache configuration file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?:Chrome|Firefox|Safari|Edge)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/svn/
RewriteRule "^/svn(.*)$" "/usr/local/viewvc-1.1.24/bin/cgi/viewvc.cgi$1" [H=cgi-script,L]
```

It checks if the HTTP User Agent is from a browser (I only put 4 browsers for now) and if the URL begins with "/svn", then it takes the rest of the path and redirects it to the .cgi script where ViewVC is located, otherwise mod_dav_svn handles the request.  Works good so far and haven't seen any performance impact.